# Can someone review my gulpfile.js?

Tags: gulp, minify, browser-sync

For anyone trying to minify-html and gulp-sass and browser-sync below is my fixed gulpfile.js

I hope it helps someone as gulp can be difficult for new folks like myself.

```
   'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browsersync = require('browser-sync');

// BrowserSync proxy
    gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browsersync({
        proxy: "localhost:8888"
    });
});
// BrowserSync reload all Browsers
gulp.task('browsersync-reload', function () {
    browsersync.reload();

});

gulp.task('minify-html', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/*.html')
    .pipe(minifyHTML({ empty: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(browsersync.reload({ stream:true }));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('./src/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
    .pipe(browsersync.reload({ stream:true }));
});

// watch task
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function () {
  gulp.watch('./src/**/*.html', ['minify-html']);
  gulp.watch('./src/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', [ 'minify-html', 'sass', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick stab I took at refactoring your *gulpfile*. All I've done is removed some duplicated code and split up the tasks in a more logical way. The main thing I'd suggest is that you make sure each task has a single purpose, and that you use the gulp dependency system to combine them as needed.

For future reference I'd ask the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) as they are more likely to help with refactoring and code reviews.

Sorry for any mistakes, as I don't have an environment to test.

```js
// include gulp
var gulp = require('gulp'); 

// include plug-ins
var minifyHTML = require('gulp-minify-html');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

var paths = {
  html: { src: './src/*.html', dest: './' },
  css: { src: 'src/css/*.css', dest: 'css' },
};

// minify new or changed HTML pages
gulp.task('html:build', function() {
  gulp.src(paths.html.src)
    .pipe(changed(htmlDst))
    .pipe(minifyHTML())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.html.dest));
});

// CSS concat, auto-prefix and minify
gulp.task('css:build', function() {
  gulp.src(paths.css.src)
    .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.html.dest));
});

gulp.task('html:watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.html.src, ['html:build']);
});

gulp.task('css:watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(paths.css.src, ['css:build']);
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {  
  browserSync.init({
      server: "./"
  });

  gulp.watch(["css/*.css", "*.html"]).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// default gulp tasks
gulp.task('build', ['html:build', 'css:build']);
gulp.task('watch', ['html:watch', 'css:watch']);
gulp.task('default', ['build', 'watch', 'serve']);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it now. My Gulp command sometimes got stuck in a loop so I knew my code was redundant. Again I really appreciate you taking the time.